# Best IPC mechanism for passing small strings

Tags: c++, qt, ipc

I want to load both 32 and 64 bit DLLs in a 64 bit application. This is impossible to do directly, so I need to create a "loader" process for 32 and 64 bit. These 2 loader processes will gather some data from the DLLs which are mostly small strings and unload them immediately. Then the main 64bit application (the GUI) will pass a path to the DLL depending on the location to either the 32 or 64 bit loader and this process repeats. I don't know much about IPC, what mechanism should I use? I don't have any realtime or performance requirement. I plan to use Qt, so I will possibly use one of its IPC mechanisms.

Maybe the loader can just directly return required data from `stdout` like a normal console application and accept comand line arguments. This is the easiest way probably, but it would be too slow probably as the loader process will be spawned and deleted a lot of times.

Comment: See `WM_COPYDATA` _"...An application sends the WM_COPYDATA message to pass data to another application...."_  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata .  Shared memory will not work for your use-case.  Next easiest is UDP.

Comment: @RichardCritten The loader process won't have a GUI, it seems WM_COPYDATA works only with 2 GUI applications.

Comment: The Windows do not need to be visible.

Comment: I'd start with `QProcess` and either its `readAllStandardOutput()` (if the number of strings being output is small) or its `readyRead()` signal hooked to a slot that calls `readLine()` (if you expect enough output that you don't want to wait until the child process's exit before reading any of it).  If-and-when that proves to be unsatisfactory, you can start looking around for more efficient alternatives.

Comment: Named pipes was what I tried, unfortunately it doesn't work correctly, sometimes it returns garbage data sometimes it gets stuck randomly. I am leaving this project aside

Answer (score 0):

Have had same problematic to solve with 64bit GUI and 32bit DLL's.
After much testings and benchmarking on working environments, the decision was made to use Named Pipes. Qt can named pipes, WINAPI can Named Pipes and it works flawlessly and don't add additional complications to code.

Here are some helpful links:

[WINAPI Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications)

[WINAPI IPC Named Pipes Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-client)